# What is wrong with CYGWIN in the latest Windows 10?

Tags: x86, windows-10, cygwin

I had been using CYGWIN to build some makefile projects, then everything got crazy.
Maybe after a Windows 10 update?

I am using a 32-bit version of CYGWIN because I build a strict 32-bit aligned code that is not portable for 64-bit, and I don't want to get any surprises due to 32/64-bit versions.

I am using some tools like gcov for code coverage, and CYGWIN started to say I need a newer version of gcov. I tried to update, but it said, I need also the newer version of CYGWIN.

I tried to install the latest 32-Bit CYGWIN, but I am getting an error when trying to install and says "Cygwin is not supported on 32-bit windows", but my Windows is 64Bit.
I tried legacy versions of 32-bit CYGWIN, but the same error.
The latest working version setup-x86-2.919, but when you run this version, and when you choose a mirror website, it gives an error like "I need the latest version "2.924"

```
---------------------------
Cygwin Setup
---------------------------
https://polish-mirror.evolution-host.com/cygwin/x86/setup.ini line 12: The current ini file requires at least version 2.924 of setup.
Please download a newer version from https://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe
```

But, 2.924 gives errors like CYGWIN does not support 32-bit windows even on 64-Windows.
Gosh.

So, I just got blocked.

Then, I thought I can have a try on the 64-Bit Cygwin, installed, and tried to run, but when I build the makefile project, I am getting an error like;

```
/usr/include/cygwin/signal.h:102:2: error: #error unimplemented for this target
  102 | #error unimplemented for this target
```

It seems **x86_64** not provided by the environment. (I am wondering can it be about the Windows itself, maybe Windows Update)

```
#ifdef __x86_64__
...
#else
#error unimplemented for this target
#endif
```

So, I am totally blocked, I can run neither 32 nor 64-bit Cygwin on Windows 10, and I cannot find any solution.

So, can you help, how can I recover my environment?

Thank you.

Comment: I know you say you are using 64-bit Windows 10, but are you sure about that?

Comment: Just to make sure: On Windows 10 hit the start menu, click on `settings`, under `system` click on `about`. There will be `system type` listed. On my Windows 10 64-bit it says _"64-bit operating system, x64-based processor"_

Comment: You will need to use the Cygwin Time Machine, which is an archive of previous releases to find the latest 32-bit version of cygwin. There are instructions on `cygwin.com/install.html` under `Q: How can I install the last Cygwin version for an old, unsupported Windows?` for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to install the 64-bit version. If your computer has 64-bit architecture the 32-bit should work. aksley even faster, but try to install the 64-bit.
But the error

```
---------------------------
Cygwin Setup
---------------------------
https://polish-mirror.evolution-host.com/cygwin/x86/setup.ini line 12: The current iI file requires at least version 2.924 of setup.
Please download a newer version from https://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe
```

LIt slike it's not even getting it from a local file, and by reading the comments in the file you can see that it says

```
This file exists so that on running an older setup for x86, no packages are
available, and you get told to upgrade to the latest setup.  Running that will
tell you x86 isn't supported any more.
```

Resuming it's saying that Cygwin doesn't support anyany more-bit installations and that you should try to install the 64-bit.

Comment: @bener08 thank you for the comment. Ok, I can go for 64 bit CYGWIN, but as I mentioned, I already tried it and I have another problem

#error unimplemented for this target

It seem \_\_x86\_64\_\_ not there in

C:\cygwin64\usr\include\cygwin\signal.h
\n
#ifdef __x86_64__\n
...\n
#else\n
#error unimplemented for this target\n
#endif\n

Comment: Wait you're using the source code? If it's on windows you could get the exe installer and that should work. Just download it from here [x86_64](https://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe) and should work

Comment: I have used the installer you are pointing. 
I am not using the source but when you include <time.h> in your application, time.h also includes signal.h,  and there is a error because the missing \_\_x86\_64\_\_ definition

In file included from /usr/include/sys/signal.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/signal.h:6,
                 from /usr/include/time.h:158,
                 from main.c

Comment: Oh sorry, kinda dumb guy here. I think I can't give much help, but have you tried to run on wsl or a Linux environment just to test?